# How to display an external site but keep an application header

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, mobile, intel-xdk

I'm new to Phonegap and am playing around in Intel XDK. How can I load an external site but maintain my own header?

Right now, all I'm doing to load the site is

```
window.location = "http://google.com";
```

I want the image on the right.
[image]

EDIT: Using `iframe` has been suggested. I tried this, but I can't get the browser part fullscreen.

```
    <iframe src="http://www.google.com/" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you've tagged html I assume we could use an `iframe`. In your case try adding something along the lines of `<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>` and then style it to your pleasing.

Take a look at [this webpage](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) for more information on iframes.

Comment: I can't get `iframe` to take up the rest of the page. See my edit.

Comment: Ah, try adding `html,body{height:100%;}` as your page make not already be 100% height.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. My `iframe` also seemed to have some padding on the left, so I gave it absolute position: `<iframe src="http://www.google.com/" style="width:100%; height:100%; position: absolute;
    left: 0px;">`